# Alpha blending issues when using low alpha values

Tags: c++, directx-11

I know this problem may seem silly, but I'm having problems when using alpha channel values to blend textures, if my alpha values goes from 1.0 to nearly 0.501, the object fades slowly , once it gets to 0.5 or lower it simply vanishes. Here's two print screens that shows it:
[image]

Alpha set to 0.501
[image]
Alpha set to 0.5

I wanted to be able to see the tree above even at around 0.1 alpha, even though it would be barely visible and mostly transparent, instead of it just vanishing suddenly. As follows is my current code for my blend state:

```
D3D11_BLEND_DESC bd;
ZeroMemory(&bd, sizeof(D3D11_BLEND_DESC));

bd.RenderTarget->BlendEnable = true;
bd.AlphaToCoverageEnable = true;
bd.RenderTarget->RenderTargetWriteMask = D3D11_COLOR_WRITE_ENABLE_ALL;
bd.RenderTarget->SrcBlend = D3D11_BLEND_SRC_ALPHA;

bd.RenderTarget->DestBlend = D3D11_BLEND_INV_SRC_ALPHA;
bd.RenderTarget->SrcBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_INV_DEST_ALPHA;
bd.RenderTarget->DestBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_ONE;
bd.RenderTarget->BlendOp = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;
bd.RenderTarget->BlendOpAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;

hr = m_pDevice->CreateBlendState(&bd, &m_pBlendStateON);
if (FAILED(hr))
    return Log("Failed to create blend state."); // Log is just a function to register errors on my app.
```

My blend factor is defined as follows: `float BlendFactor[4] = { 0,0,0,0 };`, and my sample mask uses the default value `UINT SampleMask = 0xffffffff;`

If anyone knows what I could do to make the transparency fade slowly from 1.0f to 0.0f values it would be a great help.

**EDIT:** I've found out that if I disable `AlphaToCoverageEnable` it will not cull colors until it gets to a 0.0f alpha value, but don't know what to do because I need the `AlphaToCoverageEnable` or else this squares from the tree's branches will show up, is there any way I can change the threshold so `AlphaToCoverageEnable` only culls the colors if alpha is actually 0.0f?

Comment: What format is your *render target*?

Comment: It's set to `DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM` currently, one **possible** solution to my problem that I've found is doing pixel clipping on pixel shader and turning off z-buffer to be able to see through the transparent object, but making AlphaToCoverageEnable to work properlly would be the best option...

Comment: OK, your blend settings are a bit odd.  If you are doing additive blend, try: ``desc.RenderTarget[0].SrcBlend = desc.RenderTarget[0].SrcBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_SRC_ALPHA;`` and ``desc.RenderTarget[0].DestBlend =
desc.RenderTarget[0].DestBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_ONE;``

Comment: I've tried it here, but got the same results unfortunately. I'm starting to think this is related to my hardware, because I've tried a lot of combinations and they simply don't help in anything, once I set AlphaToCoverageEnable the object's polygons will vanish once their alpha is equal or less to 0.5

Comment: @Stark maybe your texture contains premultiplied alpha values?

Comment: @VuVirt I don't think it has, I've already tested a lot of different textures in many formats and all of them has the same behavior.